# Read Dir PHP class - only 1 file by return

Tags: php, readdir

I´m trying to write and use php classes. This is my class:

```
class UseDir
{

    public $varReadFilesFromDir;        

    public function readDir(){

        if (is_dir($this->varReadFilesFromDir)) 
        {
            if ($dirHandler = opendir($this->varReadFilesFromDir)) 
            {
                while (($getFile = readdir($dirHandler)) !== false) 
                {
                    if($getFile != "." && $getFile != ".."){

                        if (strpos($getFile, '.xml') === false){

                            continue;
                        }

                        //echo "<p>$getFile</p>";
                        //return $getFile;

                    }
                }
            }
            closedir($dirHandler);
        }
    }

}

$new_UseDir = new UseDir();

$new_UseDir->varReadFilesFromDir = "C:\dir\files";

$new_UseDir->readDir();
```

I want to get each file here and want to use another class where i can do something with the file, later. If i uncomment `//echo "<p>$getFile</p>";` it shows all file Names.

If i uncomment `//return $getFile;` and edit `echo $new_UseDir->readDir();` it shows only the first file from the directory.

**Why i get only 1 File?**

regards,
ebody

Comment: because a function can only **return** one variable, but it can **print** an infinite number.  Of course, you could build an array and return the array.

Comment: Build an array with these entries. A `return` statement will exit the function or method immediately.

Comment: Try `glob()` or `scandir()` instead.

Comment: Maybe you should look into [Generators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will only get one file, because [readdir](http://php.net/readdir) only returns one file name per call. If you want all files in the directory, you have to store each returned file name in - let's say - an array and return that array instead.